# Substitute for DROP OR CREATE in MySql

Tags: mysql, sql

I have following query which was working fine until yesterday...however due to xyz reason DROP and CREATE access has been revoke from ID....so is there any way to perform following query in MySql:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS temp;
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE temp
(
call_start_date_time DATE,
cust_ph_no INT(11),
actual_repeat_calls INT(11),
total_calls INT(11),
INDEX(call_start_date_time));

INSERT IGNORE INTO temp(call_start_date_time,cust_ph_no,actual_repeat_calls,total_calls) 
(SELECT DATE(call_start_date_time),cust_ph_no,count(*)-1 as actual_repeat_calls,count(*) as total_calls 
FROM call_data 
WHERE DATE(call_start_date_time) = '2016-04-30' 
AND campaign_name = 'VT' 
AND report_id = '-2' 
AND call_status_disposition NOT LIKE 'ST' 
AND campaign_type = 'ID' 
GROUP BY DATE(call_start_date_time),cust_ph_no);

SELECT call_start_date_time,(SUM(actual_repeat_calls)/SUM(total_calls)) 
as 
repeat_ratio 
FROM temp 
GROUP BY call_start_date_time;
```

Answer (score 0):

To create temporary tables, you must have the CREATE TEMPORARY TABLES privilege.

A simple alternative would be to simply delete all rows from the table:

```
delete from temp;
```

or to use TRUNCATE:

```
truncate table temp;
```

but it's not exactly the same (temporary tables are per session, and more sessions can use the same temporary table name without conflicts).

Answer (score 0):

```
select  s.*,sum(s.actual_repeat_calls) / sum(s.total_calls) as repeat_ratio
from
(
SELECT  DATE(call_start_date_time) as startdatetime,cust_ph_no,count(*)-1 as actual_repeat_calls,count(*) as total_calls 
FROM    call_data 
WHERE    DATE(call_start_date_time) = '2016-04-30' 
AND     campaign_name = 'VT' 
AND     report_id = '-2' 
AND     call_status_disposition NOT LIKE 'ST' 
AND     campaign_type = 'ID' 
GROUP BY DATE(call_start_date_time) ,cust_ph_no
) s
```

group by s.startdatetime ;

Comment: You should be able to do this using a sub-query. I have dropped cust_ph_no from the group by because it didn't seem to have any purpose. Also the repeat ratio always comes back to 0?

Comment: It's giving me incorrect numbers...query should execute datewise sum of repeat callers example if A called us 4 times & B called us 6 times then it should be 3+5(4-1 & 6-1) and finally ration should be 3+5/total_calls